# When to use verbs that end with -ась, -ся, -ось and have an argument in dative?

Tags: глаголы

Can someone explain to me in the simplest way when to use -ась, -ся, -ось?

Basically I'm confused in such context as **мне** (some verb)-ending object

Should this -ending agree with my gender or gender of the object?

Comment: or am I the object? and if so what is this "object" in example called grammatically?

Comment: Could you please provide a Russian example with a placeholder? Like *мне остал(ась) одна забава* (or whatever you mean)?

Comment: well anything that fits this pattern... e.g. мне понравилась твоя футболка... is that correct?

Comment: yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you mean, you are speaking about ergative-like constructions in Russian with logical subject in dative and logical object in nominative.

If there is an explicit object in the sentence, like:

> - Мне осталась одна забава
> - Ей шло это платье

, then the verb agrees with the logical object (which is in nominative).

Gramatically, *забава* and *платье* are still subjects in these sentences, that's why the verb agrees with them.

If there is no explicit logical object (and gramatical subject) then the verb agrees with the assumed logical object in sg. neuter:

> - Мне показалось
> - Ей было скучно

Answer (score 1):

Окончания -ось, -ась и -ся служат сокращением от подразумевающегося местоимения "себя" (в полной форме такая конструкция уже не используется и режет слух) и означают, что действие относится не к внешнему объекту, а к автору действия.

Глаголы, употребляющиеся с этими окончаниями, но употребленные без них, требуют подчиненный объект для взаимодействия:

> Рука изогнул**ась** — рука приобрела некую кривую, изогнутую форму.
>   Рука изогнула что-то — что-то было деформировано с помощью руки.

Выбор окончания зависит от рода и числа:

> дверь открыл**ась** (женский род), компьютер выключил**ся** (мужской
>   род), время кончил**ось** (средний род), мы/они раскаял**ись**
>   (множественное число)

В случае описания состояния действующий объект часто пропускается, однако подразумевается, что он среднего рода:

> Мне показал**ось**; Мне привидел**ось** (нечто).

P.S. Простите за ответ на русском, но им я владею куда лучше, чем любым другим. Надеюсь, чтение этого ответа не затруднит вас.

Comment: Ответ мне нравится, но я думаю, что "-ся" и "себя" в современном русском не эквивалентны. Можно придумать нормальные, не устаревшие употребления и с тем ("она обрадовалась дорогому подарку"), и с другим ("она часто радует себя дорогими подарками"), но значить они будут разные вещи ("радоваться" - не то же самое, что "радовать себя"). Если я вас неверно поняла, или если вы с комментарием не согласны, я с радостью поговорю об этом в чате.

Comment: Хотя "себя" в данном случае и не используется, они эквивалентны. Смотрите: "она обрадовалась подарку" - "она обрадовала себя (это неграмотно, но сохраняет смысл, корректно будет "привела себя в состояние радости") подарку.

То есть, конечно же, ни один из перечисленных мной вариантов не употребляется, но именно они подразумеваются в сокращенной форме.

Comment: Я подожду, пока Ваша репутация будет +20 и продолжу обсуждение в чате =)

Answer (score 1):

- Мне остался последний пирог (мужской род, Пирог - он)
- Мне осталась последняя булочка (женский род, Булочка - она)
- Мне осталось последнее пирожное (средний род, Пирожное - оно)

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE.  Please refrain from repeating answers previously posted unless you want to expand on them.  In this case, you are not adding any new information, though.  In addition, please explain your answer in details, rather than simply giving the examples even if the question specifically asks for an example of something.

Comment: I like it... nice and concise.. other answers great too, but this is good summary to quickly remind

Answer (score 1):

I am taking the information from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb)

> -ась for she 
>   -ся  for he 
>   -ось for it

In Russian there are no my_self, him_self it_self or her_self. This part is being appended to the end of a verb.

Examples:

> Man wounded himself - Мужчина порезался
>   Woman wounded herself - Женщина порезалась
>   Animal wounded itself - Животное порезалось